# Yeast not settling or contamination?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, secondary-fermentation, contamination, wyeast

Having trouble understanding what I'm looking at here (see pic):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLyci.jpg

Made an Amber ale with LME and used Wyeast 1332 Northwest Ale.  Racked to secondary after 2 weeks to get it off the trub and there was a fair amount of suspended matter that made it over, including a few little clumps.  I figured they'd settle but here it is 2+ weeks in secondary and they're proliferating a bit and still rising/falling and not settling.  No activity in airlock, but they must be eating something.
Are these the 1332 yeast or something different?   I'm eager to bottle but not sure if I just need to filter these clumps out or try cold crash first?  Not familiar with this strain and never had clumpy floaters this long into fermentation, so any advice would be very appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: Excellent photo and the answer from EZ sounds spot on.

Answer (score 4):

Yeast with a high floculation rate will do this, they usually break off the bottom and float up from trapped c02.

Beer looks really clear, good job.

When you rack to secondary, go ahead and let the floaters suck into the secondary, usually this is enough to break them up and let them settle.

If you don't mind the extra loss you can leave them behind.

Just noticed that is secondary, you can rack again using a hop bag to catch and break them up. Once floculated and broken up they won't rejoin and can settle. Sounds like you just needed a little more time in primary.

Answer (score 2):

From the picture it looks like normal yeast clumps to me.  Sometimes you get dried krausen falling back in the beer and it doesn't really dissolve and settle out.  Its hard to say looking at an internet picture, but that's what it looks like to me.